# Stored meta from attachment, video length?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, customization, post-meta

I am working on a function which pulls the length (in seconds) of the selected video in a custom post type, and puts this in a input.

I have come as far as this function:

```
value="<?php if ( isset ( $theme_stored_meta['background-video'] ) ) echo $theme_stored_meta['background-video'][0]; ?>"
```

This will put the URL to the video in the input box, if a video is selected.
But how do I pull the length of the selected video from postmeta?

I have looked at the postmeta, and the part with the length looks like this:

```
s:6:"length";i:108;s:16:"length_formatted";s:4:"1:48";
```

But how do I pull the first length which is formatted in seconds and use it in my function? As you can see the "length" is what I want as that is in seconds, which I need.

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is how far I have come.

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] ) ) {
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background-video-length', '22' );
}
```

Which will set the number 22 if a background-video is set in the post. But how do I get the length of the selected video instead of 22?
Found this one, but I cannot use it, I cannot figure out how to use it at all:

```
$video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_ID, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
echo $video_meta['length_formatted'];
```

I don't know how I should target the correct attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Function (here with samepl arguments) `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'yout_meta_key', true);` will automaitly transform serialzied data to array/object. If you accessing raw walue you will find function `maybe_unserialzie` usefull for deserialization.

Comment: But I don't know the $post_id, I just know the $theme_stored_meta['background-video'] which targets the uploaded/selected video attachment.